# How do I pass mapped props to a component using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a shopping cart component that I've passed a useState prop to update the number of items within the shopping cart / the amount of money that the cart is worth:

```
import { data } from "./data";

export default function StoreItems({ addToCart, Total, setTotal }) {
  const addToTotal = (data) => {
    addToCart();
    setTotal(Total + data.price);
  };
  return (
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {data.map((data) => (
              <Grid item key={data.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
                <Card>
                  <CardMedia
                    image={data.image}
                  />
                  <CardActions>
                    <div>
                      <Button>Buy</Button>
                      <Button
                        size="small"
                        sx={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
                        onClick={addToTotal}
                      >
                        Add to Cart
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
  );
}
```

The Data is a JavaScript array with objects in it that looks like:

```
export const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "item 1",
    content: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac aliquam nunc. 
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.`,
    image: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1",
    price: 5000,
  },
];
```

And the props are passed down from:

```
function Store() {
  const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);
  const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const addToCart = () => {
    setCartCount(cartCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
            <StoreItems
              Total={Total}
              setTotal={setTotal}
              addToCart={addToCart}
            />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Store;
```

Why is it that I am unable to add the price of data.price to the useState - Total object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with how you use `addToTotal` in the `StoreItems` component. First, the function expects an item of the `data` array to be passed, but you don't do that explicitly. In your implementation the function gets a click event instead of a `data` array item. Second, it's better to rename the first argument in `map`'s arrow function because it confuses the `data` array with its items. Here's how you need to update the component to make things work:

```
import { data } from "./data";

export default function StoreItems({ addToCart, Total, setTotal }) {
  const addToTotal = (item) => {
    addToCart();
    setTotal(Total + item.price);
  };
  return (
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            {data.map((item) => (
              <Grid item key={item.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
                <Card>
                  <CardMedia
                    image={data.image}
                  />
                  <CardActions>
                    <div>
                      <Button>Buy</Button>
                      <Button
                        size="small"
                        sx={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
                        onClick={() => addToTotal(item)}
                      >
                        Add to Cart
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            ))}
          </Grid>
  );
}
```

Here's a simplified playground with the fix: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-71871965?file=src%2FStoreItems.js

Answer (score 0):

First change this :  `data.map((data) => ....`

to this :

```
 data.map((item) => ....
```

You need to pass the price to the onClick Function :

```
 <Button
 size="small"
 sx={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}
 onClick={() => addToTotal(item.price)}>
 Add to Cart
 </Button>
```

and than change the addToTotal function to this :

```
const addToTotal = (price) => {
    addToCart();
    setTotal(Total + price);
  };
```